# Should [robotics] and [electronics] tags be used?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is it a good idea to tag questions with [robotics] or [electronics]?

Or should only the [robotics] tag be used, and all other questions assumed to be electronics?

Or should we adopt a system like on meta, where at least one tag MUST be specified.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a point to an electronics tag, when *every* question on the site is (at least indirectly) related to electronics.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. After all, this _is_ **electronics**.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not sure why Robotics is even in the title.  It's just a sub-field of electronics, no?  Or is this site for mechanical engineering questions, now, too?

Comment: I agree that the Robotics title should be dropped from the title. However, Rocketmagnet makes some good arguments about the breadth of field that Robotics encompasses beyond electronics here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59408 but and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/robooverflow/59414#59414 , although I don't think that all of those issues are on topic.