# Do these tags need to be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

- The [consumer-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consumer-electronics) tag has 4 of 6 questions that are closed. Should this tag just be removed all together?
- The [x10](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x10) tag has only 2 questions, of which I think both are very poor questions. Should it go away as well?
- The [class-t](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-t) tag probably wont ever get another question tagged and probably could just go away.
- The [d-class](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-class) and [class-d](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-d) tags should be merged.
- [power-factor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-factor) only has 1 closed question
- [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) and [robotics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics) were determined to not be needed [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-robotics-and-electronics-tags-be-used), but are still around and have tons of questions under them.

And many many more, is there some easy way to do tag clean up?

**And an additional related question**

As far as I can tell tags are pretty much up to mods to handle. I know a synonym can be recommended, but the users who can recommend them are fairly narrow (2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag).

Once the synonym is recommended it takes 4 other users to go up-vote the suggestion. Daniel Grillo [recommended a few](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/pic/synonyms) back in February and still only have 1 up-vote.

So how can users that actually want to help out, help out?

Comment: [power-factor] is the only one that I'd question. If we start getting more power guys, it will be more popular.  Unlike the others, there's nothing wrong with the tag itself.

Comment: @KevinVermeer are there such things as tags that have no questions? I am not up on the nitty gritty of tags. I figured the tag would just be created when a real question was asked.

Comment: I am also not up on that nitty gritty of tags.  I didn't post that as an answer because I'm waiting for someone with more experience to post.

Comment: There are tags with no questions.  In fact, there are [7 pages of them](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags?page=20&tab=popular)!

Comment: Right now I don't use tags at all because of how poorly organized they are. I think we could just remove and/or merge a bunch of them to get category of questions. At least I assume this was the original intention of SE.

Comment: All of the ones I have clicked on have 1 or more. I am also confused as to how they order them. [tag:switches] is on the last page but has 50 questions tagged. Guess it has something to do with it going to [tag:switch]. Wonder if that is a bug.

Comment: d-class and class-d should be synonyms, but I get some error about "Sorry, creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag."

Comment: @endolith that is because you haven't received 5 up votes on answers with that tag. That was what the last edit of my question was for.

Comment: Worth noting here that the system will delete tags that aren't used *anywhere* after 24 hours, and will *eventually* delete tags that are only used once...

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for letting us know! Is there any magic to the *eventually*?

Comment: @Kellen: details can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418 - it's definitely something you want to minimize if possible, but it should do a decent job of cleaning up some of the clutter without manual intervention.

Comment: @endolith only Thomas O and Brian Carlton and mods can create that synonym.

Comment: @Kellenjb: I put in the alias, but it is just a request at this point.

Comment: @Brian Since only you and Thomas have enough rep on that tag, there is no way to get it approved (it takes 4 votes plus the original request, meaning we have to have 5 people total, but we only have 2 that are even eligible) unless a mod does it. I flagged the mods awhile back to see how they want to handle tags, but still waiting for them.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/whatever-happened-to-tripath) and Kellen's comment there I just came to meta to ask about this! :-)

I don't see anything wrong with a tag which is used once and probably never will be again. Even for one question you can still use it for lookup. I see no harm in it just sitting there; it's in nobody's way.

I would clean up the ones which aren't used at all, however. If they would become relevant they can always be re-created.

And would also cleanup similar ones, like `D-class` and `class-D` can definitely be merged. Same for `X10` and `X-10`. Nobody will question that. (You may have fierce wars over which one should go...)

Tags which are off-topic (`consumer-electronics`) should go IMO.

I read somewhere that the `homework` tag is deprecated, and since then I've removed it a number of times, but it still exists and gets used for new questions. What do we do with deprecated tags? Delete them and disallow them to be re-created?

Comment: Tags with 1 use will automatically be removed after a time period(i think 6 months), it has been a while since it was discussed though, so forgive a forgetful memory.

Comment: @Kortuk - Is that sentence correct, Kortuk? ("used"?)

Comment: now it is, thanks for letting me know. Doing 5 things at once.

Comment: @kortuk is correct, a "single serving tag" that is used on only one question over a 6 month period will be culled at the end of that 6 month period.

Answer (score 1):

> - The [consumer-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consumer-electronics) tag has 4 of 6 questions that are closed. Should this tag just be removed all together?

It's gone.  Questions about designing and modifying consumer electronics are on-topic, but this would be a meta tag on those questions, and it validates off-topic questions.

> - The [x10](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x10) tag has only 2 questions, of which I think both are very poor questions. Should it go away as well?

It's gone.  Not sure who killed it.

> - The [class-t](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-t) tag probably wont ever get another question tagged and probably could just go away.

A tag for a proprietary technology from a bankrupt company?  Removed from the question.

> - The [d-class](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-class) and [class-d](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-d) tags should be merged.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms says a synonym was created by Brian Carlton.  Thanks, Brian!

I've also merged these tags, turning 4 [d-class](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-class) tags into [class-d](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-d).

> - [power-factor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-factor) only has 1 closed question

It has two now, and we also had [pfc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pfc), but I merged both into [power-factor-correction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-factor-correction).

> - [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) and [robotics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics) were determined to not be needed [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-robotics-and-electronics-tags-be-used), but are still around and have tons of questions under them.

[electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) [was burninated](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/blacklist-electronics-tag), but [robotics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics) still exists, that reference was posted before the [scope redefinition](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/electronics-and-robotics-has-been-renamed-to-electronics), and there's been [some new discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/remove-robotics-tag-from-all-questions) about whether it's still useful.